# Can RESTHeart be run on Tomcat? In my company Undertow is not an approved product

Tags: restheart

Can RESTHeart be run on Tomcat?

In my company Undertow is not an approved product.

Answer (score 1):

Restheart is a standalone process and a product on its own.

It doesn't run on tomcat neither runs "on" undertow server containers.

Nevertheless it is developed on top of undertow core library.